# Re-posting <input> value into <textarea>

Tags: javascript, html, input

I want to re-generate user's input values onto textarea with specific format.
I've created input  and 'select' with various 'options' inside as well as 'button' that triggers the function.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here..?

```
<SCRIPT>

function myFunction() {
   var finaL = document.getElementById("textArea").value;
   var spacE = " | ";

   var a = document.getElementById("input1").value;
   var b = document.getElementById("input2").value;
   var c = document.getElementById("selecT").value;

   finaL = a + spacE + b + spacE + c;
}

</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the HTML code so we can try to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code your are getting the value of the textarea and storing it in `final` variable which is just a string. What you need to do is get the reference of the textarea in the `final` variable and then set the value.

**Working Code:**

```js
function myFunction() {
    var finaL = document.getElementById("textArea");
    var spacE = " | ";
    var a = document.getElementById("input1").value;
    var b = document.getElementById("input2").value;
    var c = document.getElementById("selecT").value;
    finaL.value = a + spacE + b + spacE + c;
}
```

```html
<label for="input1">Male</label>
<input name="input1" id="input1" /> <br>
<label for="input2">Input 3</label>
<input name="input2" id="input2" /> <br>
<label for="selecT">Input 3</label>
<select id="selecT">
    <option value="Value 1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="Value 2">Value 2</option>
    <option value="Value 3">Value 3</option>
</select>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Copy</button>
<br>
<label>Result</label>
<textarea id="textArea"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

just update code to this

```
<SCRIPT>

function myFunction() {
   var finaL = document.getElementById("textArea").value;
   var spacE = " | ";

   var a = document.getElementById("input1").value;
   var b = document.getElementById("input2").value;
   var c = document.getElementById("selecT").value;

   document.getElementById("textArea").value = a + spacE + b + spacE + c;
}

</SCRIPT>
```

what i change is from this

```
value = a + spacE + b + spacE + c;
```

to this

```
document.getElementById("textArea").value = a + spacE + b + spacE + c;
```