# Add multiple input values into textarea on submit

Tags: jquery

I have a couple of input fields, the number of input fields vary based on a user entered input field. If the user enters 1 then 20 text fields and 20 emails display, if they enter 2 then 40 text fields and 40 email fields display and so on. On submission of the form I need these fields to be added to the textarea field separated by a comma. It is similar to what was done here: [Re-posting <input> value into <textarea>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59674766/re-posting-input-value-into-textarea) but due to the large number of possible fields I can't add each input as a variable. Is there an efficient way to do this considering there could be so many fields? TIA.

```
<div id="sponsor">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="email">
</div>

<textarea></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope all of your `input` will be under `div` with id `sponsor`.

1. So you can select all the `inputs` with selector `$("#sponsor input")`.
2. Get their values with `.toArray().map(x => x.value)`.
3. And join them with `,` by `.join(",")`
4. Set `id` to `textarea` so you can assign value to it.

**Note** : If you are having other inputs also inside `sponsor` which shouldn't included then you have to add class to your `input`s which you want to include and use `class` selector to get list. Suppose we add a class `input` then use `$('.input')` instead of `$("#sponsor input")`.

You can test it below.

```js
function submit() {
  var commaSeparatedValues = $("#sponsor input").toArray().map(x => x.value).join(",");      
  $("#list").val(commaSeparatedValues);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="sponsor">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="email">
</div>

<textarea id="list"></textarea>
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="submit()">
```